# CSV manipulation | Searching columns | Checking rules

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

Help is greatly appreciated!

I have a CSV that looks like this:
[CSV example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O93wy.png)

I am writing a program to check that each column holds the correct data type. For example:

1. Column 1 - Must have valid time stamp
2. Column 2 - Must hold the value 2
3. Column 4 - Must be consecutive (If not how many packets missing)
4. Column 5/6 - Calculation done on both values and outcome must much inputted value

The columns can be in different positions.

I have tried using the pandas module to give each column an 'id' using the pandas module:

```
import pandas as pd
fields = ['star_name', 'ra']

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)

print df.keys()

print df.star_name
```

However when doing the checks on the data it seems get confused. What would be the next best approach to do something like this?

I have really been killing myself over this and any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your actual data here, not a screenshot.

Comment: So what is the problem? Doing the checks, reading in the csv or something else? How is it getting confused?

Comment: Is it not easier to see as a screenshot?

Comment: The problem is finding a way to properly ID all of the data so I can do the checks on each column. Also doing this in a way that I can check consecutive sequences when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the '[csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)' module.

## Example

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    # The first line of the file is assumed to contain the column names
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    
    # Read one row at a time
    # If you need to compare with the previous row, just store that in a variable(s)
    prev_title_4_value = 0
    for row in reader:
        print(row['Title 1'], row['Title 3'])

        # Sample to illustrate how column 4 values can be compared
        curr_title_4_value = int(row['Title 4'])
        if (curr_title_4_value - prev_title_4_value) != 1:
            print 'Values are not consecutive'
        prev_title_4_value = curr_title_4_value
```

Comment: This can work. However its hard to identify if Column 4 is consecutive.

Comment: I've edited the code above to illustrate how column 4 values can be compared. Hope this helps.

Comment: jithinpt, that might just do it. Thanks a lot for the help I really appricete it

Comment: @Lewis If that solves the question, please accept the answer and close the question.